# Visual Studio saving location

Tags: visual-studio

I have a fairly large VS solution and I didn't like where it was saving it to, so I tried to change the location with a simple 'Save as.....'. Problem is, it only saved the current form to the new location and the rest of the solution is still saved to the old location. I tried to manually fix this and just ran into errors. So now, it's loading one form from one location and the rest of the solution from the old location. I want it all to be saved to the same place (preferably my choice but the old location is better than splitting it into two).

If I try to just 'Save as...' and correct the location back to the old location, it now says that I can't because the file is currently in use.

Comment: If its not under version control you can just copy/paste the solution folder.
Start the .vbproj file in the root folder next time you want to open it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem. It all still loads in correctly, but it seems to be just loading the two parts from the two locations and still saving them back to the two separate locations.

I have backed everything up and it does load in ok. But I want it all back together in the same folder so that I can back it up more easily.

I tried deleting just the files for this form from the original folder and then manually saving back there, but it still doesn't want to know. It seems determined to load and save the form files to the new location.

Comment: Put your solution back the way it was. If you need to save your form again using the original location then so be it. Once that's done, simply close VS, move the whole solution folder to the new location and then open the SLN file. Done.

Comment: This is an example of why even lone developers doing nothing but learning exercises should use source control. If you break your project, you simply roll back your changes and you're good to go. You should use Azure DevOps, which is built into VS, or GitHub or something else but use some source control.

Comment: Yeah I solved it by John's approach, put everything back the way it was and opened it from the SLN file. Actually that also worked at the new location. Opening from the program menu's or the vbproj didn't fix it, but the SLN file did. Thanks.